# cocos2dx. how to set a callback (passing an argument) after sequence of animations

Tags: c++, callback, arguments, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to set an action after a sequence of animations, basically I need to use an object (that I want to pass as argument) for a method.

The only way I've found is using CCCallFunc which is not (as far as I know) supposed to have arguments.

Does exist a sort of "callBlock" of cocos2d/objective-c ? that's an awesome insturment, I would like to know if there is something similiar with cocos2d-x

here's the code:

```
CCCallFuncND *callBack = CCCallFuncND::create(this, callfuncND_selector(MyObject::method), data);
```

since I'm trying to do it within a class (not initialized) with only static functions I cannot use "this" so I tried to set it as NULL but in this case I got an error...

Comment: isn't there a CCCallFuncND?

Comment: yep I tried but I didn't found how to pass an argument in it, I got this error: "cannot cast from type void(*)(MyObject*) to member pointer type SEL_CallFunND" (aka void(cocos2d::CCObject::*)(cocos2d::CCnode*, VOID*));

Comment: can you post the actual code you used for CCCallFuncND? You were probably just casting/passing the "data" object incorrectly.

Comment: I've edited with the code, as I said I was trying to use a static function and call another static function with an argument, for now I've just changed the code to get an object (so instead of "this" I pass the object) and now is working, but I would like to know how to pass directly a static function from a not-created class within the cccallfunc

Answer (score 2):

I had to do same thing, after running the sequence of actions: I wanted to remove sprites from the bacthNode, so that my animation frames does not appear on screen as the animation finishes so I had to pass the batch node to the function, and this is how I achieved it :-

```
CCSequence *seq=CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(
    CCAnimate::create(animation), 
    CCCallFuncO::create(
        animation, 
        callfuncO_selector(GameLayer::animationReshuffleFinished),
        (CCObject*)animBatchNode)
);
```

function you need is CCCallFuncO instead of ND here O stands for Object.

```
CCCallFuncO::create(
    animation,
    callfuncO_selector(GameLayer::animationReshuffleFinished),
    (CCObject*)animBatchNode)
```

where `animation` is my CCAnimate object
`animationReshuffleFinished` is the call back function of my class GameLayer which I want to be called as the animation finishes. 
and `(CCObject*)animBatchNode)` is the argument to the function animationReshuffleFinished

and here is the definition of function

```
 void GameLayer::animationReshuffleFinished(CCObject *sender){
    CCSpriteBatchNode *animBatchNode = (CCSpriteBatchNode*) sender;
    animBatchNode->cocos2d::CCNode::removeAllChildrenWithCleanup(true);
    }
```

please let me know if this serves your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You just can not. If you check the definition of SEL_CallFuncXXX, you will found function must be a member function of CCObject.

Current cocos2d-x callback is totally copy from cocos2d but the Objective-C manner is not fit to C++. The limitations are:

1, might not work if you pass a object which has multi base class.

2, can not pass parameter which allocate on stack such as XXX::f(bool), you can not pass bool in it.

3, as you question mentioned, the callback function mush be a member function of a class which derived from CCObject. So static function or global function can not use

May be you are curious why they don't use std::function & std::bind instead, well, may be they copied cocos2d too fast and have not time to think about it.

Comment: +1 "May be you are curious why they don't use std::function & std::bind instead, well, may be they copied cocos2d too fast and have not time to think about it." My thoughts exactly.